# Asymptotically flat initial data sets for Schwarzschild

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, black-holes, metric-tensor

Wald Ch 11, problem 3 b reads:

> "Show that every $t$ = constant hypersurface in the Schwarzschild solution is is an asymptotically flat initial data set."

The metric for Schwarzschild is of course $$ds^2 = -(1-2m/r)dt^2 + (1-2m/r)^{-1}dr^2 + r^2(d\theta^2 + sin^2\theta d\phi^2)$$ and so I take $$ds^2 = (1-2m/r)^{-1}dr^2 + r^2(d\theta^2 + sin^2\theta d\phi^2)$$ as the metric for any $t$ = constant hypersurface.  On p. 281 Wald gives four requirements that need to be met to have an asymptotically flat initial data set and in problem 2 he has you work through some consequences (necessary conditions) of having an asymptotically flat initial data set.  If they were sufficient conditions, things would likely be much easier.  One thing that makes Wald's setup here difficult is that he uses Cartesiansish coordinates to define $C^{>0}$ so that is two steps away from the physical coordinates we are staring with.  In any event, I begin by changing coordinates to $R=1/r$ to get a hold on infinity.  Now our metric reads $$ds^2 = (1-2mR)^{-1}R^{-4}dR^2 + R^{-2}(d\theta^2 + sin^2\theta d\phi^2)$$  And if we take $\Omega^2=R^4$, we get an unphysical metric of  $$d{\tilde s}^2 = (1-2mR)^{-1}dR^2 + R^2(d\theta^2 + sin^2\theta d\phi^2)$$  This seems well behaved at spatial infinity.  But, problems quickly multiply.  First, the curvature diverges at $R=0$.  Is that allowed?  Can I still set up smooth Cartesianish coordinates a la p. 281?  Second, I am assuming that I will be able to just define my Cartesianish coordinates like so: $X=R\sin\theta cos\phi$ etc.  Am I right about that?  I'm basically assuming that the angular coordinates that we begin with will work perfectly fine as the angular coordinates at spatial infinity that figure in Wald's definition of a direction dependent limit.  Am I right about that?  Lastly, I have tried a variety of conformal factors of the form $R^2(1+O(R))$ (see problem 2) but I get divergence issues or trouble getting any interesting direction dependent limits.  All either go to zero or a constant or diverge.  None seem to give me trig functions as R goes to zero.

I suspect that I am making some mistake here at the outset in one of my assumptions.  Can anybody see some obvious mistake in my approach?

Comment: I'm trying to resubmit this for review.

Comment: I think it should be reopened